# Googledrive API: Shared Drive access control

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-workspace, service-accounts, google-api-java-client

1. I was able to create a shared drive under my profile.
2. I created `Service Account (E.g: test@svc.company.net)`
3. I created `G-Suite Account (E.g: test@integration-24524514.iam.gserviceaccount.com)` from `Service Account (E.g: test@svc.company.net)`
4. For the shareddrive created, I assigned below access for each of the profile

- My profile (**Manager**)
- Service Account (E.g: test@svc.company.net) (**Manager**)
- G-Suite Account (E.g: test@integration-24524514.iam.gserviceaccount.com) (**Manager**)

5. I created a sub folder under the shared drive
6. I tried to grant access manually from the API Explorer (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) with below details

*Request parameters*
fileId = Ix6yw5La5iTg-n*********

*Request body*
{
"role": "reader",
"type": "user",
"emailAddress": "test@email.com"
}

- It works fine when I grant access as My profile (**Manager**) and Service Account (E.g: test@svc.company.net) (**Manager**)

5. When I try the same through API as G-Suite Account (E.g: test@integration-24524514.iam.gserviceaccount.com) (**Manager**), it returns below error

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "fileId",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "File not found: Ix6yw5La5iTg-n*********",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "File not found: Ix6yw5La5iTg-n*********"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The service account doesn't directly have access to anything dont look at `test@integration-24524514.iam.gserviceaccount.com` as a user account its not.

For a service account to access files on Google workspace it needs to have [impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) set up.

Think of impersonation as a singer pending to be Mikael Jackson at a concert.  The singer has been granted permission to pretend or impersonate Mickael jackson.  They are allowed to preform as him.

For the service account to be able to access a file owned by `test@email.com` it must have permission to impersonate `test@email.com` other wise it doesn't have access.

So if you want the service account to preform actions on behalf of a user and access files owned by that user then you need to set up impersonation.

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("MyProject-1234.json"))
.createScoped(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN))
.createDelegated("test@email.com");
```